# Dual Monitor Issue - Motherboard output goes blank upon login screen

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, multiple-monitors

I have a Z97X-Gaming 3 motherboard with an integrated graphics card and additionally, I have NVIDIA RTX 2080Ti.

One display is connected to NVIDIA HDMI output and another is connected to the motherboard DVI output which is blank; initially, before the login screen, I can see the output text Ubuntu but then the login screen appears on another monitor which is connected to NVIDIA graphics card and the initial monitor goes blank.

I tried to modify the bios settings but all the attempts were unsuccessful.

Here are the current settings:
[image]

and these are the graphic cards:

```
~ lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'; uname -a
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915
--
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GV102 (rev a1)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 8667
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_drm, nvidia
Linux helix 4.15.0-76-generic #86-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jan 17 17:24:28 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I would appreciate if anyone provided any suggestion about how to enable double output.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by editing xorg.conf.

There I added additional sections for device, screen, and monitor. The modified sections, related to display settings look like following now:

```
Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Unknown"
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    # HorizSync source: edid, VertRefresh source: edid
    Identifier     "Monitor1"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Philips"
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device1"
    Driver         "intel"
    VendorName     "Intel Corporation"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen1"
    Device         "Device1"
    Monitor        "Monitor1"
    DefaultDepth    24
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```